# Is this relationship already known?

Tags: square-numbers

I like math because it's a puzzle to me, but am really not very good at it. But I figured out the relationship below myself. Just curious, is this already pretty common knowledge? Kind of proud of myself for figuring it out, but my son who's getting math minor had never heard of it. Apologies in advance for any poor explanation.

$b^2 = a^2 + a + b$ for positive integers where $b - a = 1$

e.g.
$2^2 = 4$

$3^2 = 9$

$4 + (2 + 3) = 9$

$4^2 = 16$

$9 + (3 + 4) = 16$

and so on.

Edit in response to @fleablood comment:
Where b = a + 2
Even numbers...
2^2 = 4      -> a^2 = a2
4^2 = 16     -> b^2 = b2 
16 - 4 = 12  -> b2 - a2 = c
(a + 1) * b = 3 * 4 = c
Odd Numbers...
3^2 = 9      -> a^2 = a2
5^2 = 25     -> b^2 = b2
25 - 9 = 16  -> b2 - a2 = c
(a + 1) * b = 4 * 5 = 20
c != 20

Comment: Your chance of stumbling upon something novel with such basic arithmetic is pretty remote.  But I commend your enthusiasm.

Comment: No doubt! But it's a step forward for me.

Comment: Discovering something that is both new and interesting is really hard. But trying something, noticing a pattern, and formalizing it is (I think) how a lot of math gets done, so even if it's not _new_ math, it's still math. Good for you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $$b=a+1$$

This implies

$$b^2=(a+1)^2=a^2+2a+1=a^2+a+a+1=a^2+a+b$$

Comment: Thanks Peter & @adjan. Giving the answer credit to Peter because he was first, but both are good answers. Except not sure what double headed arrows mean. Anyways, now working on a formula for  a^2 and (a + 2) ^2. So far, seems to be a different relationship depending on if the integers are odd or even.

Comment: Not really.  $(a + 2)^2 = a^2 + 4a + 4 = a^2 + (2(a+1) + 1) + (2a + 1)$

Comment: If $b = a+2$ then $b^2=(a+2)^2=a^2+4a+4=a^2+2a+2(a+2)=a^2+2a+2b$.

Comment: double arrows mean that if one of the statements is true it implies the other one is true and likewise if the other one is true the first one is.  We call it "if and only if".  It's an if statement that works both ways.  $a$ is even => $a + 1$ is odd.  That's a one way implicatation  $a + 1$ is odd => $a$ is even.  That's another one-way implication.  So $a+1$ is odd <=> $a$ is even.  "a plus one is odd if and only if a is even".

Comment: Ok, thanks. Edited original post. Like I said, not that good at math. Come from more of a programming background. Kind of wondering if different ways would be faster than others.

Comment: @recurvata In general, $b^2-a^2=(b+a)(b-a)$. You can rearrange that to $b^2=a^2+a(b-a)+b(b-a)$. So if $b=a+x$, then $b^2=a^2+xa+xb$.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. Can be easily derived:

$$b^2 = a^2 + a + b$$

$$\iff b^2 -a^2 =  a + b$$

$$\iff (b -a)(b+a) =  a + b$$

$$\iff b -a =  1 \lor a + b = 0$$

Comment: Rather sloppy! The last line is false: we could have $a+b=0$ instead of $b-a=1$. (The backward implication is true, which is what the OP asked about.)

Comment: @TonyK yes fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way of stating that $n^2 = 1 + 3 + 5 + ...$; the sum of the first n-1 odd numbers.

$a - b = 1$ means $a = b + 1$ means $a + b = 2b + 1$ means $a + b$ is the (b-1)-th odd number.

So $a^2 = b^2 + a + b$ is the same as saying $(b + 1)^2 = b^2 + (b + 1) + b = b^2 + 2b + 1$; which can be shown by expansion: $(b + 1)(b+1) = b(b+1) + (b + 1) = b^2 + b  +b + 1 = b^2 + 2b + 1$.

Expanding it is $a^2 = a + b + b + (b-1) + (b-1) + .... + 1 + 1$ = $a + 2(a-1) + 2(a - 2) + .... + 4 + 2$.

... which is another way of saying $a^2 = 1 + (1+2) + (2+3) + .... + ((a - 2) + (a-1)) + ((a-1) + a)$.

... which is another way of saying $a^2 = 1 + 3 + 5 + ... [2(a-1) + 1]$

... which is another way of saying $a^2 = (a -1)^2 + 2(a-1) + 1$

I remember being surprised when I first discovered it, too.

Comment: I get a little lost as you get deeper into it, but I really like your first statement. That is a really elegant and understandable way of stating it.
This is one of the things I like about math, and why I wish I was better at it. It's seeing the relationships between things at some kind of fundamental level. It's an awesome accomplishment that math, an intellectual construct, can actually model the universe.

Comment: Another way of looking at it is $(a + 1)^2 - a^2 = 2a + 1$ which is always odd and an odd that increases by two each time . $4-1 =3; 9-4 =5; 16-9 = 7; 25 - 16 = 9;$ etc.  This all comes for $(a + 1) ^2 = a^2 + (2a + 1)$.

Comment: Three things I'm proud of of discovering on my own in Jr. High: 1) $1 + .... + n = n(n+1)/2$. 2)$1 + 3 + ... + 2n - 1 = n^2$ which I figured went $1 + 3 ... = x$ then $2x = (1 + 3 + ... + 2n-1) + (2n-1 + 2n -3 + ....+ 3 + 1) = (1 + 2n -1) + (3 + 2n - 3) + ... (2n -3 + 3) + (2n -1 + 1) = 2n + 2n + ...+2n = n*2n = 2n^2$.

Answer (score 1):

I would prove it this way:
\begin{align}
b^2&=a^2+a+b&\iff\\
b^2-b&=a^2+a&\iff\\
(b-1)(b)&=(a)(a+1)
\end{align}
which is clearly true if $b=a+1$.